# Liquibase generateChangelog creates wrong precision for Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, liquibase

For some reason when I generate a change log with Liquibase it uses wrong precision. It generates a column with data type NUMBER(0,-127).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Please show us the changeset.

Answer (score 0):

```
<changeSet author="sfasdf (generated)" id="1357744702717-1">
    <createTable schemaName="BLA" tableName="ADT_PAGE_ACCESS">
        <column name="ID" type="NUMBER(0,-127)">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="ADT_PAGE_ACCESS_PK" primaryKeyTablespace="ZON_IND1"/>
        </column>
        <column name="PAGE_ID" type="VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column defaultValueComputed="sysdate" name="ACCESSED" type="DATE">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" type="NUMBER(0,-127)"/>
        <column name="USERID" type="VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```